# How to setup more complex membership prices

Tags: civimember, joomla

I am implementing CiviCRM in Joomla for a sporting organization. The way they work is they charge an annual membership for each of their affiliated clubs (e.g. 100$). The clubs also need to pay a certain amount for each of their members (e.g. 5$ per member). So the final membership cost of a club that has 10 members would be 150$ (100$ + (10 x 5$)). I have set up the contacts so that each club member individual is related to the club organization as a "is a member of" relationship. I have created a "club" membership at 100$ and a "club member" membership at 5$.

My question is: Is there a way of programming the membership renewal price set to automatically fetch the number of related contacts and incorporate it into the club's bill?

Thanks for any insight into this matter.

P.S.
I started with defining the club members with a "club member" membership but this created the problem that the individuals were indicated as owing 5$ in their profile and I still could not figure out how to have the number of related members in the club's bill.

Comment: I could see a way of doing this but only via an extension. not sure i would persist with the 2 membership types. if there was a field that 'counted' the number of relationships (perhaps as a new field option in Summary Fields) and then applied that to a Price Set you would get the total required. But this involved development work. If you have the right skills then you may get more useful pointers via chat.civicrm.org

Comment: Paying for development $ to get an extension written for your org is certainly an option but will only last until you run into the next more complicated thing you'd like to do. Consider switching over to Drupal and you'll have Drupal Webform CiviCRM module out of the box. It can do multiple Memberships, add orgs + individuals, add relationships etc - all on one form. And I'm not as up to date on Wordpress as I am on Drupal Webform but I wouldn't be surprised if the Wordpress Caldera Forms integration can do this as well now.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will probably go with a developper.